# How to debug `native Objective C code` in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode9, react-native-ios

I'm using react native in my ios project. I can see all the logs from react native side in chrome console, and some auto generated logs in xcode.

I recently ran into a problem while using Firebase dynamic links in my app. There is a native module `LinkManager` which basically handles all the dynamic links to the app and sends the parsed url or the deeplink to my app.

But this is not working and I understood that the problem is inside the native module that handles it.

But when I try to give NSLogs, no output appears in the xcode console, nor in the simulator console(cmd + /). I'm wondering how can I debug the native code inside xcode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to open your project in xCode and run it in any simulator. Then you can either add breakpoints on the desired line of code or use NSLogs to degug it or if it is crashing at a particular point, you can add a exception breakpoint in project.

Comment: I did the same thing, but the NSLogs don't appear. How can I be sure that a file in which I give NSLogs is executed

Comment: You can always search if LinkManager is being initialised right after your didFinishLaunching calls in AppDelegate or in your initial controller file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see logs from native code in XCode debug together with your `console.log` from JS code, you can do it like this:

```
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

RCTLog(@"Hello world");
```

Comment: Does this work for you now?

Comment: @Romick sorry, can't check, I didn't touch React Native for several months now and don't have the dev environment setup